# how to downgrade a statement for SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Following snippet works within SSIS 2012 --- derive colum block.

```
TOKEN(REPLACE(@[User::FileName],".csv",""),"\\",TOKENCOUNT(REPLACE(@[User::FileName],".csv",""),"\\"))
```

But it does not work within SSIS 2005. TOKENCOUNT was not recongnized according to the error dialog. Any suggestions which alternative could be used?

Comment: What version of SSIS are you trying to find compatibility for?

Comment: existing 2012 stuff down to 2005 (no joke). sql servers are dev edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REPLACE(RIGHT(@[User::FileName],FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileName]),"\\",1)-1),".csv","")
```

Comment: a parenthesis was removed when using your solution. thx a lot.

Comment: Whoops!  Corrected.